# Google oAuth in Cloud funtions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

i create some app that's work with gmail. But I use the authorization code from the documentation and gmail, in order to complete it, I need to open a link in the browser that will complete the authentication, but how can I do this in the cloud function where this is, in principle, not possible?

```
"""Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'gmail-sms-e30e484e728e.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    request = {
        'labelIds': ['INBOX'],
        'topicName': 'projects/sms-service-1606905645083/topics/sms'
    }
    results = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id).execute()
    messages = results.get('messages', [])
    last_message_id = messages[0].get('id')
    notification_txt = show_chatty_threads(service, last_message_id)
    plivo_send_message(notification_txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to open a link in the browser that will complete the
> authentication, but how can I do this in the cloud function where this
> is, in principle, not possible?

Your cannot do this in Cloud Functions. Google requires the user to interact with a web browser to authorize their account.

For services like Cloud Functions you either need the credentials (Access or Identity Token) passed to you or you need to use a service account.